# failed to enable x11 forwarding

Tags: unix, xorg, putty, freebsd, x11-forwarding

I am trying to enable X11 forwarding on my server which is running on FreeBSD 7.1.

I have a putty installed in my windows in which i have enabled X11 forwarding by

> checking on Enable X11 forwarding

and specifying following parameter

> X display location  **localhost:0**

after that i run putty and checked whether X11 is enabled or not by typing following command

> echo "$DISPLAY" or echo $DISPLAY

but i am getting following error

> DISPLAY: Undefined variable.

Even i have installed XManager but in that also i am getting following error

> The X11 forwarding request was
>   rejected ! To solve this problem,
>   please turn on the X11 forwarding
>   features of the remote SSH server

can anyone suggest me how to get rid off this ?

Comment: Did you try turning on the X11 forwarding features on the server?

Comment: that is what i am trying but i am getting failed whatever i tried till now is listed above

Answer (score 1):

Putty is not enough to enable X11 forwarding on Windows, you must have a X Server installed too.

You can for example install Cygwin X : http://x.cygwin.com/

Comment: I just assumed he had. Another is [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have installed the xauth package. 
It should be in the ports tree under `x11/xauth`

Just enabling X11 forwarding in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` list not the complete solution

The same applies to Linux operating systems
If you get no DISPLAY variable you might install the xauth package and you are done

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you need the following lines:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

The second line above is the default. The value controls the starting `DISPLAY` for forwarded display numbers.

Comment: Well , i have found this lines under sshd_config file and i edit it using VI editor by removing # in front of them , but still getting the same problem

Comment: @Hunt: You may need to `pkill -SIGHUP -fx /usr/sbin/sshd` to get `sshd` to re-read the config file.

Comment: I tried the above command but the effect is same . still it is not enabled :(

Comment: @Hunt: You do have an X server installed on your local machine, don't you?

Comment: no i don't have X Server installed , is it required ? could you explain the procedure

Comment: @Hunt: Yes, it's required. Choose either Cygwin X or Xming (I prefer Xming) and follow the link in Krtek's answer (or my comment to that answer) and install the server on your local machine using the instructions at the link. Note that in terms of X11, "server" means something different than you might expect.

Comment: so after installing do i still need to configure above mentioned attribute via putty .. bcoz i haven't passed that stage yet.

Comment: @Hunt: Yes, the remote system needs to be configured to forward X11 and the local system needs something to forward it to. Once everything is set up, you can use PuTTY to ssh to the remote host. On the remote host, you can start an X11 client (e.g. emacs or xeyes). Sshd then forwards the output to the X11 server on your local machine via the ssh connection through PuTTY. Then the X11 server displays the output.

Comment: i have installed xServer on my windows machine , i opened it and a white window appears now i really don't have any idea what to do

Comment: @Hunt: Which one? I'll assume Xming. You may want to have it run in Multiple Window mode instead of On Window mode. In any case, you should be able to start PuTTY, ssh to your remote host and start an X client. You haven't said what it is you want to run, but you can try xeyes, gedit, gnome-terminal, or whatever you'd like that's installed on the remote system.

Comment: first i start putty having remotely connected with my server which is running Freebsd 7.1 after that i started the Xserver of CygwinX now both the shells are open but when i tried on jar file it is still displaying "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set". this jar file has the GUI.

Comment: is freebsd os is creating a problem because i tired on my another server which is running UBUNTU , i tired xclock and everything is running fine

Comment: I have installed xclock on my freebsd servver and after editing config file i restart the sshd using /etc/rc.d/sshd restart command and  try to run xclock so now it is showing me 

Error: Can't open display: